# How to add css class to block using mytheme_preprocess_block() hook?

Tags: 7, theming

I need to add some css classes to each list item in a menu block that I created. I thought I could accomplish this by using the following code:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_block(&$vars) {

  if ($vars['block_html_id'] == 'block-menu-block-7') {
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($vars['elements']['#content'] as $key => &$item) {
      // get each list item and add some css
      if (strpos($key, '#') === FALSE) {
        $item['#attributes']['class'][] = 'col-' . $i++;
        if ($i > 3) {
          $i = 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However when I try this, I do not see the new class being added when I inspect the element although it does look like it is being added with this code. What am I doing wrong? I am using Drupal 7 by the way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['block_html_id'] == 'block-menu-block-7') {
    $vars['classes_array'][] = 'CSS_CLASS_NAME';
  }
}
```

If you want to add a class to each individual item (li or/and a)use something like this:

```
function MYTHEME_menu_link(array $variables) {
  // replace MENU-MACHINE-NAME appropriately
  if ($variables['element']['#original_link']['menu_name'] == 'MENU-MACHINE-NAME') {
    // Add menu-li class to each li 
    $variables['element']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'menu-li';
    // Add menu-li-a class to each anchor link
    $variables['element']['#localized_options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'menu-li-a';
  }
  return theme_menu_link($variables);
}
```

Comment: I need to add a class to each item (in this case an li element) and hence the foreach loop. I believe this just wraps then entire block with the given class.

Comment: Then please be more specific, your questions said "I need to add some css classes to a menu block that I created" please revisit/edit your question

Comment: I tried your suggestion and while I can see that this should work it doesn't in my case. There appears to be something that is overwriting the classes because my changes don't show up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Menu attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> This simple module allows you to specify some additional attributes for menu items such as id, name, class, style, and rel.
>
> You should use this module when:
>
> - You want to "nofollow" certain menu items to sculpt the flow of PageRank through your site
> - You want to give a menu item an ID so you can easily select it using jQuery
> - You want to add additional classes or styles to a menu item