# Set CSS class for the comment block

Tags: hooks

Could you please advice how to set additional CSS class for the comment block using Drupal hook. I'd like to paint the author and date of the comment with green color if the author of comment is not the author of a node.

Something like

```
function custom_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

    if ($author_comment_id !== $author_node_id) {

        $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'add-class';
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't see the #attributes for comment block via dsm ($form). Maybe I'm using the wrong hook? Is there any different way to achive this?

Could you please help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add css class to block using mytheme\_preprocess\_block() hook?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/88666/how-to-add-css-class-to-block-using-mytheme-preprocess-block-hook)

Comment: Thanks! I don't think this is exactly what I need. I need to operate with uid and comment blocks.

Comment: What you mean by comment block? What you show is a hook for altering the form created by another module, not a block.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. I mean comment, not a block.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it by adding a new template for the block. See [Drupal 7 Template (Theme Hook) Suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656)

> block--[region|[module|--delta]].tpl.php base template: block.tpl.php
> Theme hook suggestions are made based on these factors, listed from
> the most specific template to the least. Drupal will use the most
> specific template it finds:
>
> block--module--delta.tpl.php
>
> block--module.tpl.php
>
> block--region.tpl.php

Answer (score 0):

You may use this function [`template_preprocess_comment`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/function/template_preprocess_comment/7)

> template_preprocess_comment(&$variables)

Comment: Looks like it's what I need. I'll try. Thanks a lot!